# Manipulation of the nth term in the proof of convergence of sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Show that {$\frac{2n+1}{n+3}$} converges to 2 as $n$ tends to infinity.

**My method**

Let $\epsilon>0$.
Consider $|a_{n} - 2| = |\frac{2n+1}{n+3} - 2| = \frac{5}{n+3}$.

The next step is to put $\frac{5}{n+3} < \epsilon$, and find the $m$ for which $|a_{n} - 2|< \epsilon$ for all $n\ge$ $m$. I solved the inequality and found that $m$ is an integer greater than $\frac{5}{\epsilon}-3$. This means for any $n\ge$$\frac{5}{\epsilon}-3$, $a_{n}$ will lie between $2-\epsilon$ and $2+\epsilon$. If you take $\epsilon=1$, we can see that $m=3$, which means from the third term of the sequence onwards, value of $a_{n}$ will lie between $1$ and $3$. Here, $m$ is the least positive integer onwards which the value of $a_{n}$ will lie between $1$ and $3$.

**Method 2**

But in another proof I saw, the inequality chosen was $\frac{5}{n} < \epsilon$ instead of $\frac{5}{n+3} < \epsilon$. Although you do get a valid statement in the end, I didn't clearly understand **why** you can take $\frac{5}{n} < \epsilon$ instead of $\frac{5}{n+3} < \epsilon$. (I know that $\frac{5}{n+3} < \frac{5}{n}$, but I'm still not able to get complete clarity on the matter, so please explain that a bit.) Also, if you take $\epsilon=1$, we can see that $m=6$, which means from the sixth term of the sequence onwards, value of $a_{n}$ will lie between $1$ and $3$. Although that statement is logically correct, $6$ is not the least positive integer onwards which the value of $a_{n}$ will lie between $1$ and $3$.

Comment: Well, if $\ \frac{5}{n} < \varepsilon,\ $ then $\ \frac{5}{n+3} < \varepsilon,\ $ so finding $\ m\ $ such that $\ \frac{5}{n} < \varepsilon\ $ for all $\ n\geq m\ $ is good enough.

Comment: This is reasoning by sufficient condition (a bit backwards). For this condition to be true, it suffices that... Here we do not need equivalence and the smallest value of the integer n for which the inequality is true does not interest us.

Comment: @AdamRubinson If $\frac{5}{n} < \varepsilon$, then $\frac{5}{n+3} < \varepsilon$, but the reverse implication is not logical. I.e. $\frac{5}{n+3} < \varepsilon$ does not logically imply that $\frac{5}{n} < \varepsilon$. Here it is the latter.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette I see. So if we are asked to find the least positive integer for which the inequality is true (or the convergence begins to happen for the given $\epsilon$), then this manipulation shouldn't be done, right?

Comment: @Curiouserandcuriouser Yes, to get the least positive integer, you must proceed by equivalence.